# Can we skip entire cest class in codeception?

Tags: php, testing, automated-tests, codeception

I need to skip all the tests in the following cest class and currently I am skipping individual tests with @skip annotation. Is there any way I can skip execution at the class level itself, instead of individually skipping each test?

Currently I am skipping individual tests like this:

```
Class MyTests{

    /**
     * @skip Skip message
     */
   public funtion test1(){
    // Test steps
     }
    
    /**
     * @skip Skip message
     */
   public function test2(){
     // Test steps
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested it with Codeception 5 and `@skip message` works above class too.

I discovered a number of related issues and raised https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/6615

Comment: Thanks for the response. I put the skip annotation at class level like below but it did not work, can you pls confirm is this the right way I am following @Nakibalda? /**
 * @skip message
 */
Class MyTests{
}

Comment: What version of Codeception do you use?

Comment: I use version 4.2.2

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Codeception 4 you can exclude test with `@group` Annotation.

```
// codeception.yml
settings:
     excludeGroups: ["skip"]

// class MyTests
/**
 * @group skip
 */
class MyTests{
```